# Float versus Integer arithmetic performance on modern chips

Tags: floating-point, performance, integer, math

Consider a Viterbi decoder on an additive model. It spends its time doing additions and comparisons. Now, consider two: one with C/C++ `float` as the data type, and another with `int`. On modern chips, would you expect `int` to run significantly faster than `float`? Or will the wonders of pipelining (and the absence of multiplication and division) make it all come out about even?

Comment: Normally, I'd say that you should measure both approaches and see which one is faster. However, this is more useful/realistic if you either have access to the CPUs you want to target, or if you have simulators for them.

Comment: CPU's I've got. I was hoping that someone else had been here for  comparable computation before I go to the trouble of measuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by *significantly*.  I usually expect to see ints perform about 2x faster, but it all depends on what else is going on.  Modern processors that can handle the AMD64 (AMD/Core2) instruction set can usually do effectively 1 float operation per cycle *if they can keep the pipeline fed*

They can also usually do 2 or 3 integer operations in the same amount of time. and even can do both at once.

But it's not that hard to write code that stalls the pipeline, you have to avoid using the result of a calculation immediately after it's complete or the pipeline will stall and you get more like 3 cycles per multiply rather than 1.

The instructions per cycle for the PowerPC is the same or better than AMD/Intel in most cases.

Addendum:

By the way, you may discover that the comparisons (or rather the branches that the comparisons imply) end up costing a lot more than the additions.  mis-predicted branches are expensive, especially on the Pentium 4 processor.

Comment: Some compilers implement comparisons using the `SETcc` instructions rather than the `Jcc` instructions, in which case no branching is involved and you don't get the branch misprediction penalty.